Itavia flight 870: How accurately can the aircraft crash be reconstructed with current technique?
This question is related to the Itavia flight 870. A passenger airliner Douglas DC-9 that crashed into the Mediterranean in 1980. Surprisingly to me the causes of the crash have never been clearly found. The two most likely causes seem to be a bomb on board or a missile from a military plane.
Given that the relict of the plane has been recovered, I assume that different types of explosion leave different trace on the airplane parts. My question is:
with 2024 technical knowledge should it be possible to discriminate the causes of the crash?

Sad to be said but... welcome to the '80s Italy. The Italian Wikipedia (here the English translation) has a good overview of the whole "story" about this "incident", Tom Clancy couldn't have written a better novel.

"should it be possible to discriminate the causes of the crash?" Do I miss something or only opinions can be provided? Discussing what can be changed in the investigation conclusions looks like discussing the causes before the investigation is closed.

@mins The point of the question is exactly to understand if it is possible to discriminate the two likely causes. If it is a matter of opinions then it means it is not possible. This would indeed be an answer.

So the remains of the crashed DC-9 have been in the ocean for over 40 years?  What might be possible with modern investigative techniques examining a recently crashed aircraft is going to be far better than what can be done with something that's been deteriorating for 40+ years in salt water & ocean currents. Maybe if you get lucky an investigator can distinguish between fragments punching through the skin from the inside out instead of from the outside in, but that's hardly modern science to see that... if the remains even have that level of visible detail left.

@RalphJ: 95% of the airplane lies in a museum. No window exploded outward and the restroom (where supposedly the bomb was located) is still intact.
